Where is git-prompt.sh located in Ubuntu 24.04?
I am trying to customize PS1 so it shows the branch I am when I enter a git repository. To do that I use the __git_ps1 function and everything works fine.
My issue is that, according to the explanations I have searched over the Internet, you have to source the git-prompt.sh file into your .bashrc file. Well, I have not done it and it still works.
In fact, I tried to locate and find such script and it does not exist in my file system. So my question is, where is such function defined?

It's located at /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt:
$ dpkg -L git | grep prompt
/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt
/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt

and is sourced automatically as part of the bash completions mechanism:
$ cat /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt
# In git versions < 1.7.12, this shell library was part of the
# git completion script.
#
# Some users rely on the __git_ps1 function becoming available
# when bash-completion is loaded.  Continue to load this library
# at bash-completion startup for now, to ease the transition to a
# world order where the prompt function is requested separately.
#
if [[ -e /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt ]]; then
        . /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt
fi


I found this function in /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt but I'm not sure how that got sourced in my default config.

Ahh!  Good idea, hadn't thought to look in dpkg -L
